# Razor - cannot get refresh on PartialViewResult - javascript not rendering result

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, razor

Having problems getting a refresh on a partial view. Just trying to get this simple _MyTest to display pageNumber 2 after invoking method: OnPostSetPage(). When running OnPostSetPage(), tt looks like the return of PartialViewResult is setup correctly but not getting the refresh on screen. I'm guessing because the javascript "function setPage(pageNum)" is not handling the result and re-rendering the partial view. (In this case I have the javascript as a proxy handler because normally a href cannot do a post).

My Models:

```
public class MyReportModel
{
    const int defaultDays = 30;

    public ChkParams chkParams { get; set; }
    public string searchTerm { get; set; }
    public int days { get; set; } = defaultDays;
    public Pager pager { get; set; }
    public SortOrder sortOrder { get; set; } = SortOrder.none;
    public IEnumerable<Reports> results { get; set; }
}
public class Pager
{
    const float resultsPerPage = 100f;
    const int startPageNum = 1;

    public float pageResults { get; set; } = resultsPerPage;
    public double pageCount { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber { get; set; } = startPageNum;
    public int nextPageNumber { get; set; }
    public int resultsCount { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@page "{handler?}"
@model PretripReporting.Web.Pages.MyReports.IndexModel

<div class="card mb-5 page-card">
    . . .
    <div id="dvMyTest">
        <partial name="_MyTest" model="Model" />
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <script>

        function setPage(pageNum) {
            alert("setPage(pageNum) " + pageNum);
            var reportUrl = '/myreports/index/setpage';
            $('#nextPageNumber').val(pageNum);
            var formData = $('#frmMyReportSetPage').serializeArray();
            $.post(reportUrl, formData)
            .done(function (response) {
                alert("setPage .done");
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("setPage  .fail");
            })
            .always(function () {
                alert("setPage  .always");
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

_MyTest.cshtml

```
@model PretripReporting.Web.Pages.MyReports.IndexModel
<div id="MyTest">
    <hr />
    <p>Hello - _MyTest</p>
    <p>Page Number: @Model.myReportModel.pager.pageNumber</p>

    <a class="" onclick="setPage(2);">setPage : 2</a>
</div>
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSetPage()
{
    await getResults();

    myReportModel.pager.pageNumber = 2;

    PartialViewResult result = new PartialViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "_MyTest",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<IndexModel>(ViewData, this)
    };

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the refresh:

```
$(reportContainer).html(response);
```

setPage:

```
function setPage(pageNum) {
    ...

    $.post(reportUrl, formData)
    .done(function (response) {
        $(reportContainer).html(response);
    })

    ...

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).